# Can't program daisy device from VSCode - openocd can't find libusb

Tags: vscode-tasks, openocd

I am trying to debug my daisy program but I can't get VSCode to program the device, even though it works from the command line.

When I do `task program` from the command palette I get

> openocd -s /usr/local/share/openocd/scripts -f interface/stlink.cfg -f target/stm32h7x.cfg 
> -c "program ./build/PickupMachine.elf verify reset exit"
> dyld[62640]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libusb-compat/lib/libusb-0.1.4.dylib
> Referenced from: <2AF14ADF-FE69-3018-B458-47925DB060E7> /Library/DaisyToolchain/0.1.3-ARM/openocd/bin/openocd
> Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/libusb-compat/lib/libusb-0.1.4.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/opt/libusb-compat/lib/libusb-0.1.4.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/opt/libusb-compat/lib/libusb-0.1.4.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libusb-0.1.4.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libusb-0.1.4.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
> make: *** [program] Abort trap: 6

I tried `brew reinstall libusb`

The same command works from the command line:

> ➜  PickupMachine git:(main) ✗ openocd -s /usr/local/share/openocd/scripts -f interface/stlink.cfg -f target/stm32h7x.cfg 
> -c "program ./build/PickupMachine.elf verify reset exit"
> Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0
> Licensed under GNU GPL v2
> For bug reports, read
> http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
> Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "hla_swd". To override use 'transport select '.
> Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
> Info : clock speed 1800 kHz
> Info : STLINK V3J7M2 (API v3) VID:PID 0483:374E
> Info : Target voltage: 3.297018
> Info : stm32h7x.cpu0: hardware has 8 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
> Info : starting gdb server for stm32h7x.cpu0 on 3333
> Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
> target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread
> xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x080005e0 msp: 0x20020000
> Info : Unable to match requested speed 4000 kHz, using 3300 kHz
> Info : Unable to match requested speed 4000 kHz, using 3300 kHz
> ** Programming Started **
> Info : Device: STM32H74x/75x
> Info : flash size probed value 128
> Info : STM32H7 flash has a single bank
> Info : Bank (0) size is 128 kb, base address is 0x08000000
> Info : Padding image section 1 at 0x08011c50 with 16 bytes (bank write end alignment)
> Warn : Adding extra erase range, 0x08011c60 .. 0x0801ffff
> ** Programming Finished **
> ** Verify Started **
> ** Verified OK **
> ** Resetting Target **
> shutdown command invoked

Answer (score 0):

The issue had to do with VSCode still using the old brew locations. If I install VSCode via brew (ironically) it looks for openocd, arm-none-eabi-gcc in the old `/usr/bin` folder. If I download VSCode using the Apple Silicon link at [the visual studio site](https://code.visualstudio.com/download#) then it correctly uses the `/opt/homebrew` folder.